# How to print tesseract result in chinese characters

Tags: python, tesseract

I am trying get my program to recognize chinese using Tesseract, and it works. The only problem that I am running into is that instread of printing the result as chinese characters, the result is bring printed in Pinyin(how you would type the chinese words as english).

```py
# Import libraries
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from unidecode import unidecode

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

image_counter = 2

filelimit = image_counter - 1

outfile = "out_text.txt"

f = open(outfile, "a")

for i in range(1, filelimit + 1):
    print("ran")
    filename = "page_" + str(i) + ".png"

    # Recognize the text as string in image using pytesserct
    text = unidecode(((pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename), lang = "chi_sim"))))

    print(text)
```

this is the image i ran

[image: this is the image i ran]

this is what I got

`ran
Qing  Ming  Shi  Jie  Yu  Fen  Fen  , Lu  Shang  Xing  Ren  Yu  Duan  Que 
Xin  Wen  Jiu  Jia  He  Chu  You  , Mu  Yi  Tong  Zhi  Qiang  Hua  Cun  .`

the result should be in the chinese character as shown in the image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pytesseract foreign language extraction using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691829/pytesseract-foreign-language-extraction-using-python)

Answer (score 5):

Never mind, I realized my problem.

```py
text = unidecode(((pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename), lang = "chi_sim"))))
```

should be

```py
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename), lang = "chi_tra")
```